# Android - Appwidget with Remoteviews not updating after reboot

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview, appwidgetprovider, samsung-touchwiz

I saw similar questions here on SO, but nothing seems to work in my case...

I created an appwidget with an `AdapterViewFlipper` (Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that have been added to it). The appwidget has a Next button that enables the user to navigate to the next view on the widget.

It all works fine when I first add the appwidget. But if the smartphone reboots, the Next button of the widget no longer works on my Samsung S4 (the method `onReceive` is called, but nothings happens, it doesn't navigate to the next view and is stuck at the first view). I have to delete the widget and add it again in order for it to work...

I suspect that it is a problem of Touchwiz since I tested it on another phone (Moto G) and it worked fine.

Here are some portions of my code :

**AppWidgetProvider**

```
public class AppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static final String NEXT_ACTION = VersionUtil.getPackageName() + ".action.NEXT";
private static final String TAG = DailyAppWidget.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, colorValue);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId, int primaryColor) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewFlipperWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    // When intents are compared, the extras are ignored, so we need to embed the extras
    // into the data so that the extras will not be ignored.
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    // Instantiate the RemoteViews object for the app widget layout.
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);

    // open the activity from the widget
    Intent intentApp = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intentApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentApp, 0);
    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_title, pendingIntent);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.adapter_flipper, intent);
    } else {
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.adapter_flipper, intent);
    }

    // Bind the click intent for the next button on the widget
    final Intent nextIntent = new Intent(context,
            AppWidgetProvider.class);
    nextIntent.setAction(AppWidgetProvider.NEXT_ACTION);
    nextIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    final PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(context, 0, nextIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_btn_next, nextPendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, mRemoteViews);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(NEXT_ACTION)) {
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.daily_app_widget);

        rv.showNext(R.id.adapter_flipper);

        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive APPWIDGET ID " + appWidgetId);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).partiallyUpdateAppWidget(
                appWidgetId, rv);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

**Service**

```
public class FlipperRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

private Context mContext;
private int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;

private static final String TAG = "FILPPERWIDGET";

public FlipperRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    //... get the data
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate()");
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDataSetChanged()");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //... return size of dataset
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getViewAt()" + position);

    RemoteViews page = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget_item);
    //... set the data on the layout

    return page;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    Log.i(TAG, "getLoadingView()");
    return new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_loading);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    Log.i(TAG, "getViewTypeCount()");
    return 1;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getItemId()");
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    Log.i(TAG, "hasStableIds()");
    return true;
}
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".AppWidgetProvider"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:enabled="@bool/is_at_least_12_api">
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/app_widget_info" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<!-- Service serving the RemoteViews to the collection widget -->
<service android:name=".ViewFlipperWidgetService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
    android:exported="false" />
```

**app wigdet info**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/app_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/app_widget"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="14400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen" />
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the launcher, there is no guarantee that your `AppWidget` will be updated immediately after the device started.  It may be refreshed immeidately, or wait till the `updatePeriodMillis` passed after system started.

To solve your problem, define a `BroadcastReceiver` that will trigger the update of `AppWidget` after the reboot.

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, define the `BootReceiver` to get the boot_complete message.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And define the `BootReceiver.java` to start your `AppWidgetUpdateService`

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        //start appwidget update service  
    }
}
```